# On using pointer to access elements of a 3D array

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have an 3D array declared like this

```
unsigned char   ScalingList[3][2][64];
```

I need to access the elements of ScalingLists using another pointer, something on these lines

```
unsigned char (*pQM)[2][64];
pQM = &(ScalingList[0][0][0]);
```

and then index into the elements of ScalingList like this

```
pQM[i][j][k]
```

I know I need to have proper combination of (), * and &, but I'm not able to get it. Could someone please help me out..

Comment: @Avi Berger: you are right! Deleting against mis-understandings.

Answer (score 2):

What you posted looks pretty close to perfect to me. The only issue that I can spot is a type mismatch in the line:

```
pQM = &(ScalingList[0][0][0]);
```

The rhs as written is of type unsigned char *.

Try instead:

```
pQM = ScalingList;
```

The first dimension will decay to a pointer to the first element - a correctly sized 2-d array.